# I want to update DATETIME but i cannot be changed. it takes current time by default in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have a column datatype `datetimeoffset`. When I update it with previous years values, then execute the query, what I get is the current date and time values.

[image]

I want to change to 2015 instead of 2017 but I cannot change it. It takes current time by default in SQL Server.

Comment: Please include your SQL query.

Comment: Can you check that the column does not have a default value or the table does not have any triggers?

Comment: i dont have any trigger and also not set any default value

Comment: Please post the Data Definition Language for your table

Comment: in data definition Language My Column Datatype Is :   datetimeoffset(7)

Comment: **How** are you trying to update the value? Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
update table  set UpdatedAt = DATEADD(year, -1, UpdatedAt ) where condition
```

Comment: Wrong answer!! its not working.. please give me proper answer... and thanks for answer

Comment: Then you should provide schema of the table and what error when you are doing updating. The answer is only  based on the limited information you are giving out.

Comment: Your query is right! And i already use this query its work fine for other column date but this one only updateAt column not updated... do you have any other idea???

Comment: @ Aftab please  provide your schema definition

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1topTo2VcUVJPdNdVHH_7UQ-tWuI98tqOY9OoQnXV27s/edit?usp=sharing